# How I'm suppose to validate a DTO?

Tags: c#, .net, api, validation, dto

I'm trying to create a web API with .net in C#

Although in my research I've encountered that is a big no-no placing validation code or data annotations attributes in dtos, every tutorial that I see has something among this lines

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(SomeDto someDto)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid){
         //DoStuff();
     }
}
```

If i'm not wrong, the ModelState.IsValid check if the argument fullfills the validations requirement of the SomeDto dto. In example:

```
public class SomeDto    
{
    [Range(0, 10, ErrorMessage = "Price cannot be more that 10")] //this
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Hence my question, should I place data annotations or any validation logic inside DTOs or not? how would it be the "cleaner" solution to this?

Comment: How do you define "cleaner?"  Without the annotations you would have to write the validation code yourself.  Would that be "cleaner?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Exactly! why wouldn't I use data annotations in dtos if it suits like a charm for this scenario?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from writing your own validation code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be overkill for this case?

Comment: That's your decision to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to implement more complex logic for validation it's better to use tools like `FluentValidator`. In this case, you can separate classes and define custom validation logic and use validation attributes for the action or something like this:

```
var validationResult = new MyModelValidator().Validate(dto);
```

Separating validation logic from the model definition file makes it possible for validating a `dto` for Create and Update in different ways. The validator will be like this:

```
public class MyModelValidator: AbstractValidator<SomeDto>
    {
        public MyModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Id)
                .Empty()
                .WithMessage(DefaultMessages.InvalidInput);

            RuleFor(x => x.Name)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage(DefaultMessages.InvalidName)
                .Length(2, 80)
                .WithMessage(DefaultMessages.InvalidName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't knew this aproach, i'll check this out. Thanks!